# Deleting a file after user download it

Tags: php

I am using this for sending file to user

```
header('Content-type:  application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
readfile($file);
```

I want to delete this file after user downloads it, how can i do this?

EDIT: My scenario is like that, when user hits download button, my script will create a temporary zip file and user download it then that temp zip file will be deleted.

EDIT2: OK best way seems running a cron job that will be cleaning temp files once an hour.

EDIT3: I tested my script with `unlink`, it works unless user cancel the download. If user cancel the download, zip file stays on the server. So that is enough for now. :)

EDIT4: WOW! `connection_aborted()` made the trick !

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
if (connection_aborted()) {
    unlink($f);
}
```

This one will delete the file even if user cancel the download.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if download is completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563187/check-if-download-is-completed)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
unlink($filename);
```

This will delete the file.

It needs to be combined with [`ignore_user_abort()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/function.ignore_user_abort) so that the `unlink` is still executed even the user canceled the download.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);

...

unlink($f);
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to not serve the file up directly from the disk and, instead, use a unique URL that you can disable after the download request.

Comment: my scenario is like that, when user hits download button, my script will create a temp. zip file and user download it then that temp zip file will be deleted

Comment: @Ahmet vardar: Why not just echo out the content of the Zip?

Comment: @Billy: cuz if i do that, there will no download navigation for user

Comment: @Ahmet vardar: What do you mean by that? You're calling `readfile`. `readfile` reads and echos a file. It makes more sense to just echo the data directly instead of saving it to a file and then calling `readfile` on it.

Comment: What about the accelerators that make multiple requests?

Comment: @George Edison: *Bill turns off resume support. Accelerators unhappy. Bill happy :D

Answer (score 31):

I always use the following solution, using [register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php):

```
register_shutdown_function('unlink', $file);
```

Comment: Perfect for my situation where the file needed to exist while the function ran, but once the script was entirely done, it successfully deleted the temp file.

Comment: performs best with `ignore_user_abort(true);`, imho should be accepted anwser

Comment: This solution fixed my issue where calling ob_end_flush() seemed to end execution of the script (even though an unlink was called on the next line).

Answer (score 9):

There is no any correct way to detect whether file was completely downloaded by user or not.
So the best way will be to delete file after some period of inactivity.

Comment: I think its better to setup a Cron job to delete file after some time, say 5 minutes after the download was initiated for the file.  (assuming the download does not take more than 5 minutes though).

Answer (score 8):

`connection_aborted()` never worked for me. 
Although `ob_clean()` works exactly as it should. Hope this help others aswell

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
ob_clean();
flush();
if (readfile($file))
{
  unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: connection_aborted() didn't work for me, but this did the trick

Comment: @Sebi `readfile()` sends the file to the browser

Comment: Okay, but the creator of this post uses incorrect HTTP headers. `readfile` does not respect Byte Ranges nor is it safe to assume that the entire file has been transmitted to the user if `readfile` returns. `chunked` Encoding without `Accept-Ranges` would be a far better choice unless some Range Header processing is taking place.

Comment: It's the best option! Thank's.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find something which worked for me, so I came up with this, which seems to work well for me:

```
header('Content-type: application/zip'); //this could be a different header 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zipName.'"');

ignore_user_abort(true);

$context = stream_context_create();
$file = fopen($zipName, 'rb', FALSE, $context);
while(!feof($file))
{
    echo stream_get_contents($file, 2014);
}
fclose($file);
flush();
if (file_exists($zipName)) {
    unlink( $zipName );
}
```

I hope that helps someone

Answer (score 3):

I too have very similar functionality in one of my website. It will be like deleting randomly created folder & zip file after/cancelling download. I try to explain it here, may be someone find it useful.

**skin.php:**
This page contains download link such as "http://mysite.com/downoload/bluetheme"

**.htaccess:**
I have following rule in htaccess file to redirect the download request to a php file. [download.php].

```
RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ download.php?file=$1 [L]
```

**download.php:**

```
include "class.snippets.php";
$sn=new snippets();
$theme=$_GET['file'];
$file=$sn->create_zip($theme);
$path="skins/tmp/$file/$file.zip";
$config_file="skins/tmp/$file/xconfig.php";
$dir="skins/tmp/$file";

$file.=".zip";
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($path);

//remove file after download  
unlink($path);
unlink($config_file);
rmdir($dir);
```

so on request download.php will create directory with a random name using snippets class. Inside the directory it will create a zip file. after the download/cancelling the request all the files and the directory will be deleted.

Comment: If user cancels the download or closes his browser before the `readfile()` function completes, can you guarantee that script execution is not terminated resulting in `unlink()` never getting called?

Answer (score 0):

For those who face the "extra bytes at the begining of file" issue, I would recommend to add buffer cleaning functions before readfile, as suggested in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083411/16381972

```
@ob_start('');  //@ supresses a warning  
//header entries
ob_end_clean();
ob_clean();
readfile($file);
```