# php download files with readfile and then delete problem

Tags: php, download

Hello I use the following script for downloading files with php:

```
$archive = tempnam("//somepath/mms_1/MMS_SERVICE/","asset");
$zipobject = new ZipArchive();
$zipobject->open($archive, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zipobject->addFile('somefile', '');
......
$zipobject->close();

$filesize = filesize($archive);

$timestamp=date('d-m-y_H-i');
header("Content-type: application/x-zip-compressed");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Assets_$timestamp.zip  ");
header("Content-Description: Download PHP");
header("Content-Length: filesize ");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile_chunked($archive);
unlink($archive);
```

The problem is that php do not delete the temp zip file when finish downloading, or when user aborts downloading, or when leave page. It seems that unlink never executes in this cases ignore_user_abort(true); function but this doesnt resolve the problem.
Any one can suggest a solution for this?

Comment: What's the code for `readfile_chunked();`? If it opens a file pointer are you sure it's being closed again?

Comment: It's similiar to readfile(), but even using readfile gives the same problems.

Comment: You can try with the solution described here 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641667/deleting-a-file-after-user-download-it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [register-shutdown](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) call in php to have your cleanup function **always** run.

Comment: are you sure the apache user (or any other PHP owner user) can delete files in this directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
$filesize = filesize($archive);  
$timestamp=date('d-m-y_H-i'); 
header("Content-type: application/x-zip-compressed"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=Assets_$timestamp.zip  "); 
header("Content-Description: Download PHP"); 
header("Content-Length:" **.$filesize** ); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
if ($archive != ''){ 
 $fileData = @file_get_contents($archive);
 echo $fileData;
 unlink($archive);
}
```

try the suggestion above. I have not attempted your version, but this works for me, so barring any access issues, it should work for you too. (I have marked in bold (double stars)the code I have changed from your version)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you specified ignore_user_abort(true); ?
It need to be before readfile