# return binary code instead of string in response php

Tags: php, excel, binary

I want to read an excel file with php and send its content to the client. What I really want to do is by changing the content type and other html headers force browser to download the file instead of showing its content. Everything is ok and user can download the file but when he tries to open it contents are not displayed in right format and shape. The thing which comes to my mind is that I should not send response in unicode string and have to do it in binary format which excel can know it. This is my current code  :

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
        $ext = $_GET['type'];
        $filename .= '.' . $ext;
        $path = "../generatedReports/" . $filename;
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public", false);
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
        $size = filesize($path);
        $f = fopen($path, 'r');
        $content = fread($f, $size);
        echo $content;
```

Any solution?

Comment: please attach the excel that you get

Comment: So what does the file content look like? Is the file you're downloading an Excel file, or simply CSV or HTML with a .xls extension?

Comment: @Deep: how can I attach file?

Comment: Ensure that there is nothing in your script that echoes or prints any other output from PHP, including whitespaces and BOM markers. Open the downloaded file in a text editor, and check for any leading or trailing whitespace that might be indicative of this, or for any obvious plaintext PHP error messages.... if you have to use ob_clean() then you're outputting something else in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was solved by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041597/1570631). I've changed my code to this :

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
            $ext = $_GET['type'];
            $filename .= '.' . $ext;
            $path = "../generatedReports/" . $filename;
            header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: public", false);
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            ob_clean();   // discard any data in the output buffer (if possible)
            flush();      // flush headers (if pos
            readfile($path);
```

and everything got nice.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code,

```
echo unicode2utf8(hexdec("00CE")); // Result: Î

// Or the function that will recognize U+ in front of string, and will skip it to show the character
function unicodeCodePointToChar($str) {
    if (substr($str,0,2) != "U+") return $str;
    $str = substr($str,2); // Skip U+
    return unicode_to_utf8(array(hexdec($str)));
}
echo unicodeCodePointToChar("U+00CE"); // Result: Î
```