# How to return an image to an https request with PHP

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, silex

After many hours,

I nailed down my problem concerning downloading an image with an https request.
When I access an image with the hard path `(https://mysite/tmp/file.jpg)`, apache
returns it with success and I can view it in the browser, without any extra manipulation.
When I try to access it with another path 
`(https://mysite/files/file.jpg)`, in order to control its access with php, I get
a response from my php code, but I cannot view the image in the browser.

- VirtualHost defined; mysite: set to /var/www/mysite
- $app['controllers']->requireHttps();

**Description of the environment:**

```
mysite/tmp/file.jpg          
mysite/files/.htaccess
            //... no files; handled by Silex router. here is the .htaccess:
            ---
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule ^ ../web/index.php [L]
            </IfModule>
            ---
```

- https:// mysite/tmp/file.jpg,    served with https:200 and viewed in browser; ok
- https:// mysite/files/file.jpg   served with https:200 ***but not*** viewed in browser; ?

Here are the 3 methods tried:

**Method 1: Silex sendFile() direct method >**

```
$app->get('/files/{onefile}', function ($onefile) use ($app) {    
    // Validate authorization;  if ok, then
    return $app->sendFile('/var/www/mysite/tmp/' . $onefile);
});
```

**Method 2: Silex Streaming >**

```
$app->get('/files/{onefile}', function ($onefile) use ($app) {   
    // Validate authorization;  if ok, then
   $stream = function () use ($file) {
       readfile($file);
   };
   return $app->stream($stream, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
```

**Method 3: Symfony2 style >**

```
$app->get('/files/{onefile}', function ($onefile) use ($app) {   
    // Validate authorization;  if ok, then
    $exactFile="/var/www/mysite/tmp/" . $onefile;
    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () use ($exactFile) {
        $fp = fopen($exactFile, 'rb');
        fpassthru($fp);
    });
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($exactFile));
    $response->headers->set('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
    $response->headers->set('Accept-Ranges','bytes');
    $response->send();
```

This is what Chrome presents:

[image]

**With this Chrome image this is the Http (Https or not, same result) request**

```
Request URL:https://mysite/files/tmpphp0XkXn9.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers:
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:XDEBUG_SESSION=netbeans-xdebug; _MYCOOKIE=u1k1vafhaqik2d4jknko3c94j1
Host:mysite
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

Response Headers:
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive, Keep-Alive
Content-Length:39497
Content-Type:image/jpg
Date:Thu, 13 Jun 2013 13:44:55 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15
```

**Other tests made to eliminate possible undesired behavior:**

- I checked the BOM and made sure the php code responding to the request is valid 
  and do not have undesired byte-order marks (BOMs) using Emacs (`set-buffer-file-coding-system utf-8`).  Furthermore, to avoid unknown BOM tagged files, I executed the following command in the mysite directory (`grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' .`). Nothing abnormal appeared.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the files (image) received by the browser (`save as` on each image), this is what the tool (Hex Friend) help me to find, but I still do not understand why:

Comparing the two files

- (one with success: mysite/tmp/file.jpg ; served ***directly by Apache***)
- (one with NO success: mysite/files/file.jpg; served ***by a PHP script***).

*At the beginning of the binary file, I get this difference:*
[image]

*At the end of the binary file, I get this difference:*
[image]

**Question:**
How can I return an image (in stream or some other technique) with a php code, and view it in the browser ?  All php code methods return the same output, I suspect an environment problem.  Is there an environment setting that could produce the error I am experimenting ?

Comment: What do you want? display or download the picture ? first sentence in question talks about downloading. then you would need the content-disposition header aswell. btw. cleared your browser and app cache? :)

Comment: Ok, I will clarify the question in the main text.

Comment: Clearing the browser's cache had no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not happy with this solution (A ***PATCH***), but the problem is fixed, by adding the following call:

```
$app->get('/files/{onefile}', function ($onefile) use ($app) {    
  ob_end_clean();  // ob_clean() gave me the same result.
...
}
```

Ok, it is fixed, but, can somebody explain to me how to fix it more intelligently ?

**UPDATE**

*What happened ?:*

This is what my interpretation:
Extra newlines remains in the orignal php raw files to a unintentionally position!  It turns out that when you have a php file

```
<?php
...
?>
```

where you left some newlines (or spaces) after the `?>`, those newlines will add up in the output buffer.  Then trying to stream a file to the output will take these add up newlines and put them where they belong: in the header stream, or at the footer stream.  Having a fixed size for the stream (equal to the image size) will take specially the header extra characters and shift accordingly the bytes outputted to the browser.  I suspected that I add exactly 5 characters (`0A 0A 20 0A 0A`) corresponding to (`linefeed linefeed space linefeed linefeed`) discovered in the received image from the browser.  Now the browser do not recognize the image structure, being shift from the offset 0, of 5 non logical character for the binary image.  Therefore, the browser can only show a broken image icon.

Also look at: [Another helping SO fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041564/php-readfile-adding-extra-bytes-to-downloaded-file)

**Advise to PHP framework developer:**

If you provide a `sendFile()` equivalent method, maybe you should thrown an `Exception`, when `ob_get_contents()` does not return an empty buffer, just before streaming to the output !

**For now:**

This small linux batch file can at least let you find where your code should be cleaned.  After using it, I was able to remove the `ob_end_clean()`... after analyzing the output of this small script.  It tells you suspicious php files that might contain extra space or newline at the end of your php files.  Just execute and manually fix files:

```
#!/bin/bash

for phpfiles in $(ls -1R *.php); do
   hexdump -e '1/1 "%.2x"' $phpfiles | tail -1 >endofphpfile;
   if [  `cat endofphpfile` = "3f3e" ]; then
      echo "OK.................File  $phpfiles"
   else 
      thisout=`cat endofphpfile`
      echo "File  $phpfiles: Suspucious. Check ($thisout) at the EOF; it should end with '?>' (in hex 3f3e) "
   fi
done
```

It can surely be improved, but that should, at least, help anybody !

Comment: You sir, are my hero! I've spent a day on figuring out this. Adding `ob_end_clean();` to the beginning of a `StreamedResponse` callback is what I was missing in my code. I was trying to return a Postgres bytea stored image to the user, but no matter what I did - nothing worked. Thank you for sharing this answer!

Answer (score 3):

don't use the closing **?>** ... it's against symfony coding standards.

Against [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#22-files) to be more concrete.

> All PHP files MUST end with a single blank line.
>
> The closing ?> tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.

The reason for that is partly what you experienced.

This behavior is sometimes caused by the [BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php) aswell.

check none of your files contains the byte-order-mark!