# PHP File Download adds "null" at end

Tags: php

```
>         header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
>         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt");
>         header("Pragma: no-cache");
>         header("Expires: 0");
>         print "$data";
```

The file downloaded has $data in it, however always adds a "null" at the end. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: add `exit;` after `print`

Comment: what you shown us will not cause that. Show us more/full code. You also may  have whitespace somewhere. See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/8041564/

Comment: Make sure you don't have extra content before or after the opening and closing PHP tags.