# Why some code will not be ran after the header("Content-disposition: ...") line?

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone know why the code after the `header(Content-disposition: ...)` will not run? It writes and downloads the file, but it will not run the `unlink()` line...

This code is within a few other if statements originally.

Here is the code:

```
$form1Array = array($_POST["namn"], $_POST["stad"]);
$form1String = serialize($form1Array);
$form1Fil = $_POST["namn"].".txt";
$midMappe = "midlertidig\\";
$fo_form1Fil = fopen($midMappe.$form1Fil, "w");
//
if (fwrite($fo_form1Fil, $form1String)) {
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    //
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$form1Fil);
    //
    unlink($midMappe.$form1Fil);
    } else {
       echo "Could not save the file for download.";    
    }
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: I bet it runs the line, but it's unable to unlink the file. Check your error log (and make sure warnings are actually written to it)

Comment: You have an open `fopen` handle on the file, so it naturally can’t be unlinked at this point … D’oh!

Comment: @CBroe:
Haha, I did not know you needed to close it with `fclose()` before you could `unlink()` on it. Everything now works fine when I `fclose()` it first. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code will be correctly executed and as someone pointed out in the comments, it is very likely that the problem is in the `unlink()` function. I recommend you to do a quick debug and see what `unlink()` returns. More in particular, see if it return false (it will if it fails to unlink the file).

[Here an example of what i mean](https://gist.github.com/jnardiello/b89990f14e4f04169966)

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that I needed to `fclose()` the file first, hehe. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of 'CBroe', thank you.

I also added a `connection_abort()` line which I found out about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641667/deleting-a-file-after-user-download-it).

Here is the updated code:

```
$form1Array = array($_POST["namn"], $_POST["stad"]);
$form1String = serialize($form1Array);
$form1Fil = $_POST["namn"].".txt";
$midMappe = "midlertidig\\";
$fo_form1Fil = fopen($midMappe.$form1Fil, "w");
//
if (fwrite($fo_form1Fil, $form1String)) {
    fclose($fo_form1Fil); // ** Here is the updated/added line 1 **
    //
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    //
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$form1Fil);
    //
    if (connection_abort()) { // ** Here is the updated/added line 2 **
        unlink($midMappe.$form1Fil);
    } else {
        unlink($midMappe.$form1Fil);
    }
    } else {
       echo "Could not save the file for download.";    
    }
```