# Webdriver open a file as soon as it finishes downloading

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing some tests and I'm I'm using the `Firefox webdriver` with a `FirefoxProfile` to download a file from an external url, but I need to read such file as soon as it finishes downloading to retrieve some specific data.

I set my profile and driver like this:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/some/path/')
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream")

ff = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Is there some way to know when the file finishes downloading, so that I know when to call the reader function without having to poll the download directory, waiting with `time.sleep` or using any Firefox add-on?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I assume this is Linux? You could use inotify to watch the directory and handle the events. But then it would be in a different thread or process. I have example code for that if you want me to post it.

Comment: Yes, it's Linux. Could you please post it or leave a link to a gist? Whatever you want. Maybe I can figure something with it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try hooking the file up to a file object as it downloads to use it like a stream buffer, polling it as it downloads to get the data you need, monitoring for the download completion yourself directly (either by waiting for the file to be of the expected size or by assuming it is complete if there has been no new data added for a certain amount of time).

Edit:

You could try to look at the download tracking db in the profile folder as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029824/programmatically-determining-the-status-of-a-file-download).  Looks like you can wait for your file to have status 1.

Comment: Sorry but I can't afford to assume things, I need to be certain that the file is completely correct. Anyways, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use inotify to watch for these kinds of events. Some example code,

```
from pyinotify import (
    EventsCodes,
    ProcessEvent,
    Notifier,
    WatchManager,
)

class EventManager(ProcessEvent):

    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        file_path = os.path.join(event.path, event.name)
        # do something to file, you might want to wait a second here and 
        # also test for existence because ff might be making temp files 

wm = WatchManager()
notifier = Notifier(wm, EventManager())
wdd = wm.add_watch('/some/path', EventsCodes.ALL_FLAGS['IN_CLOSE_WRITE'], rec=True)

While True:
    try:
        notifier.process_events()
        if notifier.check_events():
            notifier.read_events()
    except:
        notifier.stop()
        raise
```

The notifier decides which method to call on the event manager based on the name of the event. So in this case we are only watching for `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` events

Comment: is`pyinotify` a standard package?

Comment: Nope, you'll need to `pip install pyinotify` and it is a wrapper around the inotify syscalls that are only available in Linux.

Comment: I am using windows 7 then,how would be it for mw?

Comment: You have to use something else (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows) but since Gerard said he was working on Linux that's why I provided this answer.

Comment: Then any help on the same question in window's solution?

Comment: `+1` to you for the `Linux` version, window's version would also be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't touch windows if at all possible, so wouldn't even be able to test it. However a quick google gives this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/156178-watching-a-directory-under-win32/

Answer (score 0):

It's far from ideal, however with firefox you could check the target folder for the presence of the .part file which is present while it's still downloading (with other browsers you can do something similar).
A while loop will then halt everything while waiting for the download to complete:

```
import os

def test_for_partfile():
    part_file = False
    dir = "C:\\Downloads"
    filelist = (os.listdir(dir))
    for partfile in filelist:
        if partfile.endswith('.part'):
            part_file = True
return part_file

while test_for_partfile():
    time.sleep(15)
```