# PHP, Python Django File Download Control

Tags: php, python, django

The application will send a link by SMS, the link requires OTP and after verification of OTP, a PDF document is downloaded.

How can we ensure the file is successfully downloaded and opened?

Can we have our page download the file in the background with a progress bar UI and hand over to browser/system download API only after the file is successfully downloaded in the background?

We want assurance that file is successfully received and opened.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Already following thread is discussion this scenario, having useful inputs.

[Determining successful download using php readfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771226/determining-successful-download-using-php-readfile)

[How to tell if a file was really downloaded and saved, despite browser prefetch/cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856001/how-to-tell-if-a-file-was-really-downloaded-and-saved-despite-browser-prefetch)

Comment: Thank you. I've seen those threads. But they were of not much help. I'm specifically looking for a solution on mobile - either safari on iOS or chrome on Android. Most solutions are based on file size comparison. can the new progressive web apps help? I know Safari is not yet supported.