# Attaching a token to file download?

Tags: php, sql

I have a paypal_ipn setup on my server, currently I am thinking of setting up an account based token system and restrict the token to 1 time login. Though I was wondering if its possible to attach a token to the download itself.

So it would go like this, user pays in paypal, then user is redirected to successful page after ipn verification. An email will be sent via backend automatically with the download link and token, that token should delete and the download unaccessible after the download is complete?

I want able to find clear resource of this procedure, any advice how to achieve such funcionality?
Alex

Comment: I will be passing the token to the sql db and the token should be removed after download has been successful as deemed by server preferrably php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How will you know if the user successfully downloads the file? Server Scripts can't tracked it, if you have an applet or flash the the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563187/check-if-download-is-completed) has, which is not recommended, maybe you can track it. but in your tag you haven't mentioned any client side scripts so I doubt you haven't use any of that.

It's possible to use a token to use it as an authentication but you will not able to check if the user had successfully downloaded that. You can just use the session token for the validation and it will be unable when that token expires or logout to your site but notify the user if you will use that.

Comment: How about ip restrict to token?

Comment: What if the user accidentally lost his net and his IP configuration is auto, what will happen? in session you could still get it in a period of time as long as you have set it. but it's also viable, you can choose whatever your client needs and explain the drawbacks and advantages of it.