# Laravel 5.2: How to know a file is downloaded successfully?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2.
I would want to record file's downloading,there are 3 tables：
`users` , `files` , `download_records` ,

**users**

```
id       name       password          email
1         Jim        ******           Jim@example.com
2         Charles    ******           Charles@example.com
```

**files**

```
id         file_path                  
1           /var/www/uploads/001.jpg
2           /var/www/uploads/002.doc
```

**download_records**

```
id         file_id         user_id      download_time
1            2                1          2016-04-15 09:00:00
2            1                2          2016-04-15 09:10:00
```

when a file is downloaded by someone, a record will be added into `download_records`,the question is:
How to know a file is downloaded successfully?

Comment: I think it is not possible with php, read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563187/check-if-download-is-completed