# check solution for submit button click status

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

The below code shows a method which creates a PDF file with DomPDF plugin in Laravel.

In the last line of code working as will open a dialog for saving the file.
But, this code saves "is_print" value as 1 before clicking the submit button..

Do you have any idea how to check the submit button click status in JavaScript or other?

```
public function customer(Request $request)
{
    //update "is_print" sign 0 to 1 when before Print out.
    $jobs = Job::onlyTrashed()
    ->whereIn('id', explode(', ', $request->input('job_ids')))
    ->update(['is_print' => 1]);

    //print out with name as "customer_rapport.pdf". 
    return $pdf->download('customer_rapport.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are doing this?

Comment: @buzzfizz, Sometimes it is necessary if the user closes the dialog box for saving the PDF without pressing the submit button. :)

Comment: I think this thread answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563187/check-if-download-is-completed